# Can't yank into * or + registers

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register, os-clipboard

I'm trying to yank to the system clipboard on Ubuntu 14.04. I can't yank into the + or * registers, though. Every time I visually select my text and type `"*y` or `"+y` the indicator on the bottom right initially indicates the number of lines selected (e.g. `4`) while in visual mode. After the next keystroke, `"`, it indicates that it is in operator pending mode (lists `"` instead of `4`).

As soon as I press `*` the `"` changes back to the number of lines selected (`4`). Pressing `y` after this vim reports that 4 lines were yanked. But they are definitely not in the system clipboard. The exact same thing happens when I try to store the yank in the `+` register.

Notes:

1. I have two keyboard layouts configured (Dvorak: primary, QWERTY: secondary). The same thing happens on both layouts.
2. I have stripped down my `.vimrc` to an empty file: No luck.

Comment: Has your vim been compiled with the option `+clipboard`? You can check that with the function `:version()`. More precisely you can use `:echo has('clipboard')` to check if this precise option is enabled. If it is not you'll have to recompile a vim with this option.

Comment: That's probably the problem, but you don't have to recompile to solve it. If gvim is installed, you can start it as `gvim -v` and get a terminal vim, or you can link gvim to vim, e.g., `ln /usr/bin/gvim ~/bin/vim` and make sure `~/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your PATH.

Comment: @garyjohn I don't understand how using a terminal vim instead of the gui version will enable the `clipboard` option?

Comment: @statox: The OP didn't say whether he was using vim or gvim, but this is a commonly-encountered problem with terminal vim on Ubuntu and Fedora systems, so I assumed the OP was using terminal vim. The problem is that these distributions build their vim packages without support for X, which I don't understand. They also have separate vim and gvim packages, which I don't understand, either. Gvim, of course, has support for X. Both vim and gvim binaries can be run in either terminal mode or GUI mode, depending on how they're invoked. ...

Comment: ... My proposal was for the OP to run the gvim binary, which does support X and the clipboard, in terminal mode so that the clipboard will be available.

Comment: @garyjohn Ok I understand better your suggestion now. I don't know if it's a really clean solution but that's a clever workaround :-)

Comment: @statox my vim doesn't have a `version()` function, but it does have a `:version` command. Is that a typo or is my `:version` missing `version()`?

Comment: @jjaderberg You are totally right vim doesn't have a `version()` function only a `:version` command. That was a typo, my bad. (Unfortunately I can't edit my comment anymore)

Comment: @statox It's rarely safe to say "vim doesn't have...", but I figured it was probably a mistype, thanks for clarifying. It looks like the question will be merged anyway (hmm..) so the comments will be dropped, otherwise your comment would serve well as a partial answer–"here's the first step to troubleshoot your issue...".

Comment: @jjaderberg: Are you trying to get me to unmerge this question?

Answer (score 1):

@statox and @garyjohn, thank you for taking your time to answer. I looked for solutions to this problem before I posted this (I don't like wasting my time). It seems, though, that [this has been asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347519/unable-to-copy-from-vim-to-system-clipboard).

Indeed, my version of Vim seems not to have been compiled with +clipboard (I had no idea that this was even a thing... How do you guys know everything?). `echo has('clipboard')` returns `0`.

@statox, I don't want to recompile Vim. I wouldn't be compiling it again as I downloaded a precompiled binary anyway using apt-get, the aptitude repository manager, but it would still be a pain (making would take forever for vim). So, I have installed vim-gtk and removed vim and I now have access to the system clipboard (checked over ssh). Thanks you guys for pointing me in the right direction.

There is a good StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard) that mentioned this very problem. I may have even read this yesterday when I had my problem but I don't think that I got to this really important paragraph:

> Be aware that copying/pasting from the system clipboard will not work if :echo has('clipboard') returns 0. In this case, vim is not compiled with the +clipboard feature and you'll have to install a different version or recompile it. Some linux distros supply a minimal vim installation by default, but generally if you install the vim-gtk package you can get the extra features.

Thanks, again, you guys for the help.